# Proving isometry and isomorphism of a linear operator $S: Y\rightarrow c_{0}$ that is composed of functions from the unit ball in the dual space of Y.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Y is a normed space and $B_{Y^{*}}$ is a closed unit ball of $Y^{*}$ (where $Y^{*}$ is the dual space of Y). There also exists a $0<h<1$ such that $B_{Y^{*}}\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}B(y_{j}^{*},r)$ for some $y_{1}^{*},y_{2}^{*},...,y_{n}^{*}$ in $Y^{*}$ with $\left \|y_{j}^{*}  \right \|=1 \ \ \forall j=1,...,n$. The linear map $S: Y\rightarrow c_{0}$ is defined as: $S(y)=(y_{1}^{*}(y),y_{2}^{*}(y),...,y_{n}^{*}(y),0,...) \in c_{0}$.
I am trying to show the following:

(1) $\left \|S  \right \|=1$

(2) $\left \|y  \right \|\leq \frac{1}{1-h} \left \|Sy  \right \| $

(3) S in an isomorphism and $\left \|S^{-1}\right \|\leq \frac{1}{1-h}$

For (1) I tried the following:
$\left \|Sy  \right \|=sup\left | y_{j}^{*}(y) \right | \leq sup\left \|y_{j}^{*}  \right \|\left \|y  \right \|=\left \|y  \right \| \leq1$ as $y \in B_{Y^{*}}$

To show equality I then demonstrate an instance where in the above equality holds: so I use Hahn Banach theorem to find a y (where $\left \|y  \right \|=1$)  such that one of $y_{j}^{*}(y)=\left \|y  \right \|$. We can therefore conclude $\left \|S  \right \|=1$

For (2) I tried: 
$\left \|y\right \|=sup\left \{\left \|y^{*}(y)\right \|:y^{*} \in B_{Y^{*}}\right \}$
$ \left \|y\right \|-\left \|y_{j}^{*}(y)  \right \| \leq \left \|y-y_{j}^{*}(y)  \right \|=\left \|(y-y_{j}^{*})(y)\right \| \leq\left \|(y-y_{j}^{*})\right \|\left \|y\right \|\leq h\left \|y\right \|$
Hence:

$\left \|y\right \|-\left \|y_{j}^{*}(y)  \right \|\leq h\left \|y\right \|$

$(1-h)\left \|y\right \|\leq \left \|y_{j}^{*}(y)  \right \|$

$\left \|y\right \|\leq \frac{1}{1-h} \left \|y_{j}^{*}(y)  \right \|\leq\frac{1}{1-h} \left \|Sy  \right \|_{\infty}$

Are these valid approaches?

Any suggestions for (3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(3) follows directly from (2): (2) shows $S$ is injective so inverse exists.

For (1), Hahn-Banach Theorem is not used correctly, and in fact it is not needed.
$$||S||=\sup_{x\in B_{c_0}}\max_k |y_k^*(x)|=\max_k\sup_{x\in B_{c_0}}|y_k^*(x)|=\max_k||y_k^*||=1$$